# A sequence is defined by: $a(1) = 1$ and $a(n + 1) = 3a(n) - 1$ for $n \ge 1$. What is $a(100)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

A sequence is defined by: $a(1) = 1$ and $a(n + 1) = 3a(n) - 1$ for $n \ge 1$. What is $a(100)$?

> Solution. The first few terms of $a(n)$ are $1,2,5,14,\ldots$. The general solution to the homogeneous form of the recurrence is $a(n) = c 3^n $. A specifi$c$ (constant) solution  must satisfy $x = 3x - 1$, so we find $x=1/2$. Now, assuming the general solution to the complete recurrence has the form $a(n) = c  3^n + 1/2$, and substituting $n = 1$, we see that $a(1) = 1 = 3c + 1/2$ so that $c = 1/6$. Thus, the solution we want is $a(n) = \frac{3^n}{6} +1/2 = \frac{1}{2} (3^{n-1} + 1)$. (Check that this does generate the first few terms of $a(n)$). In particular, $a(100) = \frac{1}{2} (3^{99} + 1)$.

---

My question is this, how do they get the specific or (constant) solution using the $x$ and why is it needed? (is it needed because the - 1 makes it a non homogeneous recurrence and the x = 3x -1 is just a way of finding the non homogeneous recurrences specific solution?) and why is the $x$ the same shouldn't it be something like: $x+1 = 3x - 1$ instead?

Answer (score 4):

In the original question, you have $a_{n+1}=3a_n-1$, which is complicated to deal with. So you try to construct a geometric sequence, which is much simpler.

To do that, you add a constant $c$ on both sides. $a_{n+1}+c=3a_n-1+c$ and what you want is $a_{n+1}+c=3(a_n+c)$. Solving that, you can get $c=-\cfrac{1}{2}$.

Now, you have a geometric sequence, namely $\{b_n=a_n-\cfrac{1}{2}\}$, where $\cfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=3$, and you know that $b_1=a_1-\cfrac{1}{2}=\cfrac{1}{2}$.

Then, it is easy to see that $b_{100}=\cfrac{1}{2}3^{99}$ and thus $a_{100}=\cfrac{1}{2}(3^{99}+1).$

Answer (score 2):

The theory is that the general solution to $a_{n+1} = pa_n + q$ is formed by the sum of one specific solution and solutions to $a_{n+1} = pa_n$.

To find a specific solution you can look for fixed points of the equation, that is, solutions where $a_{n+1} = a_n = x$. This gives us he equation $x = px+q$, and solving it gives us a specific solution where $a_n = x$ for every $n$.

In the equation in this exercise, you'll see that $3 \cdot \tfrac 12 -1 = \tfrac 12$, so the constant sequence $(a)_n = (\tfrac 12)$ solves the recurrence $a_{n+1} = 3a_n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Define the ordinary generating function:
$$
A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
$$
From your recurrence you get $a_0 = \frac{2}{3}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} &= 3 A(z) - \frac{1}{1 - z} \\
A(z) &= \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 3 z} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align*}
$$
This is just two geometric series:
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{6} \cdot 3^n + \frac{1}{2}
$$
So $a_{100} = 85896253455335221839410188294270212117017920334$

(Thanks [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) for help with algebra/arithmetic).